# Weird lines after transform in non-webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, rotation, webkit, transform

I am trying to make a simple CSS filmstrip. I have the general look, but when I rotate it to set it at an angle, it shows some little white lines along the "seams". I have tried playing around with `backface-visibility: hidden`, but no luck.

This works perfectly in Chrome and Opera, but it fails in IE, FireFox, and Safari.

[Here is a Fiddle to show you what I'm talking about.](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/K4K6G/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="filmstrip"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.filmstrip {
    width: 120%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px -10%;

    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    transform: rotate(-2deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
.filmstrip::before,
.filmstrip::after {

    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);

    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 100%);
    background-size:40px 40px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-width: 10px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.filmstrip::before {
    top: -40px;
}
.filmstrip::after {
    bottom: -40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your gradient filling refer the following fiddle i used skew instead of rotate http://jsfiddle.net/suriyag/LQ46D/

```
 transform: skewX(-25deg);
 -o-transform:skewX(-25deg);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, this does not give the desired look. I don't want the strip to be skewed, I want the entire thing to cross the page at a 2deg angle. Just how it appears in the original fiddle in Chrome.

Comment: for that u have to use some other things apart from gradient

Comment: Like what? Do you have a suggestion that will give me the same look?

Comment: I would like to find a solution that is pure CSS, using an image file would ruin that. However, I tested the theory anyway in my fiddle [(click here to see)](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/K4K6G/3/) and it gave me the same result. It works fine in Chrome, but fails in FireFox.

Comment: some of the css properties not works with Firefox, for example customization of scroll bar is  also not works with firefox